# Locust: Not able to send a POST Http request with OpenSSL certificate

Tags: python, openssl, locust

I am getting 403 HTTP error while sending a HTTP POST with SSL certificate. I tried to enable the debugging at the local server and it looks like locust is not sending the certs with the request which results in a 403 error. I tried python request lib and it works fine. Also, how to enable locust in verbose mode to see if it really attaches the certificate with the request?

Do you guys know how to debug this issue? The same request works fine with Postman.

```
from locust import task, tag, between
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser


class ApiClient(FastHttpUser):
  wait_time = between(0, 100)

  def on_start(self):
    self.client.verify = "~/client.crt"
    self.client.cert = ('~/client.crt', '~client.key')
  
  @task
  def get_profile(self):
    print(self.client.cert)
    resp = self.client.post("/android/callback", {
            "pcc" "123"})
    print("Response status code:", resp.status_code)
    print("Response text:", resp.text)
```

Comment: Locust's normal HttpUser is based on Python requests. Have you tried that? It's possible something is wrong/different with FastHttpUser.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use HttpUser that is based on requests framework and use instruction from official request documentation.

https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification